# Copy from S3 TO HDFS Using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hdfs

I am getting a `ConnectionTimeOutException` while writing file from S3 to HDFS.

Tried adding timeout parameter:

```
import java.io.IOException
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

val sparkSession:SparkSession=SparkSession.builder().master("yarn").appName("To hdfs").getOrCreate

sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx")
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.attempts.maximum", "30")
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.speculation", "false")
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.proxy.host","webproxy.e.corp.services")
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.proxy.port","80") 
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled","true") 
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint","s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com") 
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx") 
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2") 
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.yarn.queue","root.ecpdevingest") 
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.connection.establish.timeout","10000") 
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.connection.timeout","50000") 
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.threads.max","100") 
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.threads.core","5")  
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.multipart.size","104857600") 
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.multipart.threshold","2147483647") 
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.executor.instances", "8") 
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.executor.cores", "4") 
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.executor.memory", "32g") 
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.driver.memory", "4g") 
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.driver.cores", "2") 


val file = sparkSession.sparkContext.textFile("s3a://acrXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX5.avro", 11)
file.saveAsObjectFile("hdfs://c411apy.int.westgroup.com:8020/project/ecpdevingest/avro/100")
```

The error was:

```
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to acron-avro-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com:443 timed out
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:416)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:151)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:125)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
        at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRequest(RestStorageService.java:334)
        at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRequest(RestStorageService.java:281)
        at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRestHead(RestStorageService.java:942)
        at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.getObjectImpl(RestStora
```

Comment: Why don't you use `hadoop dist-cp` or `s3-dist-cp` ? These two tools aare optimized for this purpose. Othewise you should check your credentials, roles and network access.

Comment: connection timeout means the HTTP connection to the s3 endpoint couldn't be reached. If that is the correct endpoint name, then check the proxy settings

Answer (score 0):

the credential keys for s3a are different than s3 and s3n use keys:

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "XXX")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "XXX")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Nobody needs to set that fs.s3a.impl option. Ever. Its some superstition passed down in spark documentation that everyone repeats without understanding.
2. If you do, *do not* set the fs.s3a.impl to the S3N implementation class.  `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem`. You have done this and so not a single one of the fs.s3a options are going to be read and used.

Cut that declaration out, then try again.